# Find syscall signatures, automatically

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system, system-calls

I want to write a script (or `c` code) that can **automatically** print the list of supported sys calls (the full function signature; specially, their names, return type and argument list)?

I have searched for the solutions for a while, and know syscall names are present in . But there is no argument list or return type?

My target platform is Linux (specifically, Ubuntu) and `c` .

PS: By syscall, I mean the libc wrapper functions for syscall...

Comment: can you use [this kernel header](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L210)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @knm241 's comments, this will work:

```
grep '^asmlinkage.*sys_' /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30/include/linux/syscalls.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AWK version of @Richard's answer, that squashes multiple line definitions into one.

```
awk '/^asmlinkage.*sys_/{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " "); printf $0; while ($0 !~ /;/) { getline; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " "); printf $0 } printf "\n" }'  /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/syscalls.h
```

EDIT using man pages:

I've combined my previous answer with awking the man page which sometimes has better type information in the signature:

```
awk '
/^asmlinkage.*sys_/ {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")
    printf $0
    while ($0 !~ /;/) {
        getline
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")
        printf $0
    }
    printf "\n"
}' /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/syscalls.h | \
sed -E 's/.* sys_([_a-z0-9]+)\(.+/\1/' | \
while read syscall; do \
    man 2 "$syscall" | \
    awk '
        /DESCRIPTION/ { exit }
        /^ *[_ a-zA-Z0-9*]+ '"$syscall"'\([a-zA-Z][_0-9A-Za-z]+/ {
            gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")
            printf $0
            while ($0 !~ /;/) {
                getline
                gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")
                printf $0
            }
            printf "\n"
        }';
done
```

Note that not all syscalls have man page entries, so it's not replacing parsing the headers.